# Process builder create task

Tags: process-builder, opportunity, tasks, automation

I am trying to build an automated task using process builder when opportunity is on the specific stage. However, I have a problem with field picker. I want to assign this task to opportunity owner / the person created that opportunity.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Could you please [edit] this post to ask a clear question? Right now it's not clear whether what you have is working or not and why.

Comment: Hi David, what is the ambiguity with this question? I am trying to create an automated task using process builder. In fact, when going to another stage in opportunity, the task should be created. I do not know how should I address the field picker. (Assign  Id or related to ID).

Comment: You should associate it to the Related to ID

Comment: Hi @Raj The field should be related to ID. What about the value?

Comment: Were you ever able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try as shown in the above image.

Assigned To ID -> OwnerId

Comment: Hi Mohit, I tried but the task is not created.